# Python3: Import Module over Package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package, python-import

I'm looking for suggestions to import a module over a package in Python3. I don't have control over the names of the files so changing them is not an option. Additionally, the submodules are external github repositories that I will constantly pull updates from, hence cannot change the contents of feature.py

This is my directory structure:

```
foo
    __init__.py
    bar_1.py
    bar_2.py

submodules
    s_module_1
        foo.py
        feature.py
    s_module_2
    s_module_3

main.py
```

Contents of feature.py

```
...
from foo import foo_methods # import from foo.py module
...
```

Contents of main.py

```
from foo import * # imports from foo package
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'submodules/s_module_1')
from feature import * # results in error
```

When I run main.py, the error I get is

> ImportError: cannot import name 'foo_methods' from 'foo' (foo/__init__.py)

Any suggestions to resolve this would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried `from submodules.s_module_1.feature import *` ?

Comment: use `from .foo import foo_methods` or `from submodules.s_module_1.foo  import foo_methods`

Comment: I just edited the post to clarify that the submodules are external github repositories that I will constantly pull updates from, hence cannot change the contents of feature.py.

Comment: `from submodules.s_module_1.foo  import foo_methods` - this works fine. However I'm looking to import feature.py and that file (which I cannot change) contains the import of foo.py

Comment: `from submodules.s_module_1.feature import *` I've tried this as well, and same error